# GCP I cannot acccess my jupyter server on VM instance.(have no solution in stackoverflow)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

I create **GCP vm** instance, allow **http** access and set config **jupyter server** as below:

```
$ jupyter notebook password

c = get_config()
c.NotebookApp.ip = '10.14.~~~~~~'
c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = '*'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'
c.NotebookApp.password = "sha1:~~~~~"

$ sudo ufw allow 8888
$ jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 8888
```

and I try to connect to "`http(s)://externalip:8888`"
but failed. It only showing **infinite loading**.

here is console message:

> (base) myID@instance-1:~$ jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 8888 [I
>   07:26:32.493 NotebookApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from
>   /home/renwenxue0/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-package s/jupyterlab [I
>   07:26:32.493 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is
>   /home/renwenxue0/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab [I 07:26:32.495
>   NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/renwenxue0
>   [I 07:26:32.495 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at: [I
>   07:26:32.495 NotebookApp] http://(instance-1 or 127.0.0.1):8888/ [I
>   07:26:32.495 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut
>   down all kernels (twice to skip confirmatio n).

I have sent feedback to google team but got no reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable firewall rule on GCP console(allow port 8888)
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#firewall_rules_in

Comment: I've already set firewall rule: rull
Ingress
Apply to all 
IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
tcp:8888
Allow
1000
default. it must be correct?

Comment: Shouldn't that be 8888?

Comment: sorry misspel: I set both of 8080 and 8888

Comment: @Roy can you access in VM using internal IP? Also try `tcpdump` to check inbound requests

Comment: Oh I finally found out the problem: I set my firewall rule wrong. `Target` should have been exact `tag` or `Apply to all`. I wrongly tagged my instance. Thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have a much easier time if you use GCP's [AI Platform Notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-notebooks/) instead.

It's the same price as doing it yourself, but you'll get a full Jupyter Notebook environment with various popular ML libraries preinstalled (and GPU support for them pre-setup as well)

To create one go to the GCP console -> AI Platform -> Notebooks -> New Instance